# Most efficient way to search through rows and change values in columns of a large array (50,000 by 50,000)

Tags: algorithm

Say there is a large two dimensional array (50,000 by 50,000). Essentially all the elements in the array are 1s and 0s. I am try to figure out an efficient way to change values in columns (1s to 0s and 0s to 1s). But more importantly see which rows have matching elements (a row with all the same values).

Comment: What do you mean by "rows have matching elements"? Is it a row with all elements equal or a pair of equal (component-wise) rows?

Comment: what did you try till now?

Comment: Could you clarify the equations performed on the 2d array?

Comment: Yeah sure. Essentially I want to be able to go through every column and change 1s to 0s and vice versa. And then go through rows and see which rows have the same values (all 1s or all 0s)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could do something like

```
int[][] data = new int[1000][1000];
// populate
final Random random = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
        final int value = random.nextInt();
        data[i][j] = ((value % 2 == 0) ? 1 : 0);
    }
}
final List<BigInteger> bitStrings = new ArrayList<>();
StringBuilder builder = null;
for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
        final int value = data[i][j];
        builder.append(value);
    }
    final BigInteger bitString = new BigInteger(builder.toString(), 2);
    bitStrings.add(bitString);
}

for (final BigInteger bitString : bitStrings) {
    System.out.println(bitString.toString(2));
}
```

And use the BigInteger operations for bitwise operations.